# How to cancel a task which is not performing any loop-based statements

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have an asynchronous task that is executing a function. The function does not contains any looping statements, but instead it is executing series of sql commands on sql server. Now, i have a button on my window that can cancel these sql operations. In other words, cancel the whole asynchronous task.

I know that this technique will require CancellationTokenSource and CancellationToken to cancel the task, but i've seen many examples on the internet and all of them are showing that the function that task is executing contains loop statements in which they are checking for `IsCancellationRequested` boolean property. But in my case, it is not so. My function does not have any loop statements in which i can do a check on this boolean property.

please suggest any method/technique.

Any help will be highly appreciable...

Thanx in advance...

Comment: If those commands are not in a transaction when you cancel the commands completed I believe they will not be rolled back.  Why would a user cancel?  If this is a long running task consider BackGroundWorker with Progress so you can report back how many sql statements have been processed.

Comment: @Blam, maybe those are `SELECT`s, so rolling them back doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are really only three basic program flows: sequence (step 1, step 2 and so on), selection (if-type statements) and iteration (loops).

If you don't have any loops, all you're left with is selection and sequence. That means your code is probably going to end up looking something like (pseudo-code, obviously):

```
perform sql (statement1)
if IsCancellationRequested: return

perform sql (statement2)
if IsCancellationRequested: return
:
:
perform sql (statementN)
if IsCancellationRequested: return
```

In other words, without loops, there's no single handy place to put the check where it will be called many times, and you'll have to call it many times yourself. There's no real difference between that and calling it in a loop, in terms of the number of times it's called.

---

If your problem is that you don't like the idea of so many checks peppered throughout your source code,you can create a function to do it for you, something like:

```
def execSql (sqlStatement):
    perform sql (sqlStatement)
    return IsCancellationRequested
```

then your lines become:

```
if (perform sql (statement1)): return
if (perform sql (statement2)): return
:
if (perform sql (statementN)): return
```

Now you can probably *add* loops by putting the statements into a collection of some sort and, that way, you'll only have to code up one check/return. But that means a more substantial change to the way you do things now.

Answer (score 0):

You should check it whenever you need in your code. Your examples (the one you saw) has for, so it check for cancellation on each iteration. Since you don't have for, you will have to manually choose when you want to check if the user cancel it. Since you have querys, maybe after each query, or every 2 or 3 querys. When you need it.

Comment: @gbianchi... see the thing is that user can cancel the task at ANYTIME by clicking the button. so keeping the check after every line, i think it is a rediculous idea...

Comment: Well.. The for construction is checking it after every line ;) but you only write it one time :)

Answer (score 0):

So make them!

Simple example (You can extend it as you like):

```
List<string> _sqls = new List<string>();
_sqls.Add("Select ... ");
_sqls.Add("Update ... ");
_sqls.Add("Select ... ");

foreach (var sql in _sqls)
{
   Execute(sql);
   if (IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      // Make some rollback
      return;
   }
}
```

For better experience you can use `List<Func<..>>`, `List<Action<..>>` instead of `List<string>` or even come up with Query, Builder, Factory Method design patterns.